# Cannot import Excel sheet into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, import-from-excel

I am trying to import an Excel sheet from my computer into Jupyter Notebook. I am using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\ALL my folders\Budget_2021_Twinsies.xlsx')
```

I get a lengthy error code, the essence of which is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ALL my folders\\Budget_2021_Twinsies.xlsx'
```

I do have this file on my computer and I type in the correct directory, yet still get this error.

Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: Is "User" just a placeholder here? Might put it where ever the notebook is and see if that works first.

Comment: C:\Users\User\Desktop\ALL my folders\Budget_2021_Twinsies is the exact location of the file on my laptop. I am not entirely sure what you mean by "put it wherever the notebook is first". Apologies if that's too obvious!

Comment: So where is your .ipynb jupyter notebook file? Is it in "ALL my folders" path? If not, try making a copy of your Excel file into where you have your jupyter notebook. I'm guessing that you started jupyter notebook from some package manager so it's likely not in the same path.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, I simply needed to install openpyxl. I just did and the file was then correctly located. Many thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use the pathlib module function that always select the correct configuration for your OS.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

file = pathlib.Path(mydir, myfile)
df = pd.read_excel(file)
```